# json невалидность

Tags: php, javascript, json

Добрый день.
Мне нужно розпарсить ряд таких вот "обьектов"
**Валиден**

```
 {
        "type": "company",
        "company": "R20",
        "position": "Поставщик шин и дисков",
        "address": "Украина, Днепропетровск, Днепропетровская область, ул.Артема а",
        "emailArray": [
            "info@r25.com.ua"
        ],
        "phoneArray": [
            "380669811060",
            "380671911865"
        ],
        "urlArray": [],
        "tags": "шины,диски,поставщик",
        "comment": null,
        "source": "tyetraer.ua"
    }
```

Проблема в том что валидатор говорит что один такой валидный, а если их в файле 2 и более(пусть даже одинаковых) говорит что файл уже не валиден.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем сдесь проблема?

**Невалиден**

```
{
    "type": "company",
    "company": "R20",
    "position": "Поставщик шин и дисков",
    "address": "Украина, Днепропетровск, Днепропетровская область, ул.Артема а",
    "emailArray": [
        "info@r25.com.ua"
    ],
    "phoneArray": [
        "380669811060",
        "380671911865"
    ],
    "urlArray": [],
    "tags": "шины,диски,поставщик",
    "comment": null,
    "source": "tyetraer.ua"
}{
    "type": "company",
    "company": "R20",
    "position": "Поставщик шин и дисков",
    "address": "Украина, Днепропетровск, Днепропетровская область, ул.Артема а",
    "emailArray": [
        "info@r25.com.ua"
    ],
    "phoneArray": [
        "380669811060",
        "380671911865"
    ],
    "urlArray": [],
    "tags": "шины,диски,поставщик",
    "comment": null,
    "source": "tyetraer.ua"
}
```

Я думаю что нужно что то "предусмотреть" в синтаксисе. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем невалидность?

Comment: Ну так у вас здесь два JSON-объекта, а вы работаете с ним как с одним. Либо парсите строку вручную и генерируете нормальные json-объекты, либо переделываете файл, чтоб он содержал 1 json-объект, в котором будет массив из ваших записей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JSON вы обязательно должны использовать **единственный** корневой элемент. Поэтому, чтобы сделать второй пример валидным, можно обернуть объекты в массив:

```
[
    {
        "type": "company",
        "company": "R20",
        "position": "Поставщик шин и дисков",
        "address": "Украина, Днепропетровск, Днепропетровская область, ул.Артема а",
        "emailArray": [
            "info@r25.com.ua"
        ],
        "phoneArray": [
            "380669811060",
            "380671911865"
        ],
        "urlArray": [],
        "tags": "шины,диски,поставщик",
        "comment": null,
        "source": "tyetraer.ua"
    },
    {
        "type": "company",
        "company": "R20",
        "position": "Поставщик шин и дисков",
        "address": "Украина, Днепропетровск, Днепропетровская область, ул.Артема а",
        "emailArray": [
            "info@r25.com.ua"
        ],
        "phoneArray": [
            "380669811060",
            "380671911865"
        ],
        "urlArray": [],
        "tags": "шины,диски,поставщик",
        "comment": null,
        "source": "tyetraer.ua"
    }
]
```